# Google Places Autocomplete not showing up

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-directive, google-places-api

I've been working on this for hours trying to figure out why the supposedly simple autocomplete wasn't showing up.

It turns out that in my code, the input element is being set to `autocompete="off"`, and the style on the pac-container is `display: none`.

I can change these values in DevTools, and it works fine, but I can't figure out how or why these are being set to these values.

My autocomplete is set-up in an Angular Directive, like this, where loadGmaps gets the google api.

```
template: '<input id="google_places_ac" name="google_places_ac" type="text" class="input-block-level"/>',
link: function($scope, elm, attrs){
    loadGmaps().then(function(){

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#google_places_ac")[0], {});
    console.log(autocomplete);
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        $scope.position = {
            lat: place.geometry.location.lat(),
            lon:  place.geometry.location.lng()
        };
        $scope.$apply();
    });
});
```

---------------------Update----------------------------------------------

Hopefully nobody else is lead astray by this, the `autocomplete="off"` is a bit misleading. Even with `autocomplete="off"`, the autocomplete still works, so that wasn't the problem. I am over-writing the css of the  `.pac-container` element, which holds the results with

```
.pac-container {  //this is a fix for google autocomplete not showing up
    z-index: 10000 !important;
    display: block !important;
}
```

The problem with this is that once an item has been selected from the autocomplete, the autocomplete remains visible, I'm pretty sure there is a better way to be using autocomplete.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

For anybody else who may be stuck or having difficulty with this, ignore the 'autocomplete="no"' value, and don't use 'display: block' to show the '.pac-container'.

go into your chrome devtools and make sure you can see the `.pac-container` div. set the z-index of that div in your css. When there is a searched value, google will change the display to block and handle the showing and hiding, you just have to worry about the z-index.

Comment: Thanks, `.pac-container { z-index: 10000 !important; }` worked for me!

Comment: I'm running into this same issue, however z-index is only part of the solution. I'm still unable to get display: block to fire automatically. It is stuck at display: none. Any suggestions?

Comment: I had an input in a modal window and the pac-container appeared in back of this window. I just try `.pac-container { z-index: 10000 !important; }` on my css and works fine. Thanks!.

Comment: It really depends on the current window's z-index, in my case - kendo modal window, I have to set the z-index to 100000 to bring autocomplete, obviously kendo window modal has a higher z-index than 10000

Comment: Agree with @uowzd01. It depends on the current modal window's z-index. Mine was a primefaces dialog and I had to set z-index to 2500.

Comment: *NOTE:* Setting z-index in dev tools to test quickly did not work for me but actually setting it on the .pac-container class in my CSS did solve the problem in my case.

Comment: I've working on this issue for hours. I am using angular-ui modal with ng-maps and I wanted the place-auto-complete search box on an input. The places suggestions were not showing, then on dev tools at chrome I saw it was there but not rendering. So I just added the .pac-container with the z index and it works. This was the exact solution !!! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Had to add the style to global styles (styles.css file) in order for it to work for me. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: I am stuck on this problem. Not with z-index or anything with display:none, but on certain screensizes its being rendered off screen for some reason. Any solutions or ideas on this?

Answer (score 12):

check version of map in index file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.26&key=YOUR API KEY"></script>
```

**Specify v=3.26 when loading the Google Map API**

Comment: My code worked fine for more than a year. Just now out of the blue `style="display:none"` was added to the input element on which the directive was applied. Turned out that specifying the version of googleapis fixed it. I suppose this means that there is a conflict between the directive and the latest gmap api version.

Comment: Hey @ChrisAelbrecht, Experiencing the same problem. Can you help me with this ?

Comment: @nehasoni just load the googleapis as in the example here above

Comment: Saved my evening!

Comment: This should absolutely be the accepted answer: it fixes the problem without incurring any CSS hacks. Just saved my company -hours- of dev time hunting the problem down.

Comment: @ChrisAelbrecht Thanks. Worked for me and saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

There's another case where `.pac-container` won't show up: when u use fixed positioned containers and u leave the `<body>` without actual relative/static childs the `<body>` collapses to `0` height or to so small that the bottom edge is higher than where the `.pac-container`would appear. In such case you can see with devtools that pac-container is in right position, and has height, but not visible.

`body{min-height:calc(100vh)}` could help.

Comment: Why `calc()` for a static value?

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by [Vince Lowe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1141272/vince-lowe) in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185606/google-places-autocomplete-not-showing-up/20204015#comment36150416_20204015):

```
.pac-container { z-index: 10000 !important; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Ensure that you've enabled the Direction API on google map and that billing is enabled on the account