# ng-map and place autocomplete not working in modal

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, autocomplete, bootstrap-modal, ng-map

I am using ng-map directive and place autocomplete API in my angularjs application. which are working fine.
but the problem is I need Both in a bootstrap modal and when i am using same code in a bootstrap modal, Nothing is working neither ng-map nor place autocomplete.
Suggest me if I am missing something.
problem occures only when i use angular's ng-map directive. With javascript everything works fine but I don't want to write bulk of code. I wanna use ng-map only.
Here is my markup

```
<ng-map zoom="8">
<marker visible="true" centered="true" position="current-location" title="You are Here" draggable="true"></marker>
<marker visible="true" centered="true" position="{{vm.place.formatted_address}}" title="You are looking for this" draggable="true"></marker>
<marker ng-repeat="c in vm.cities" position="{{c.pos}}" title="{{c.name}}" id="{{c.id}}" on-click="vm.showCity(event, c)"></marker>
 <directions
        draggable="false"
        travel-mode="DRIVING"
        panel="p3"
        origin="jaipur"
        destination="Delhi">
      </directions>
  </ng-map>
```

see my 
    [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uTLTjkxjWSsKjzYGoWDi?p=preview)

for whole code

Answer (score 2):

Since the map is displayed in bootstrap modal, the map needs to be explicitly intialized once the modal dialog is opened as demonstrated below:

```
 $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
        $timeout(function() {
            google.maps.event.trigger(vm.dialogMap, 'resize');
            vm.dialogMap.setCenter(vm.mapSettings.center);
            vm.dialogMap.setZoom(vm.mapSettings.zoom);
        });
 });
```

> `'show.bs.modal'` event is triggered once the modal is opened.

From another hand, unfortunately [angularjs-google-maps](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) at the moment contains a [bug](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/issues/564) that prevents the route to be printed if multiple map instances are added into a page (in your example there are **two** map instances)
In the below example is provided a workaround.

**Working example**

The following [**forked plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/mFXGtGL2SMg9MKn8mGqk?p=preview) demonstrates how to:

- properly display map in modal dialog
- print routes in multiple map instances

Comment: You solved half of my problem. search-auto-complete still not working in modal.

Answer (score -1):

add a style 
.pac-container { z-index: 10000 !important; }

ref from there
[Google Places Autocomplete not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185606/google-places-autocomplete-not-showing-up)

here a plnkr for a your working example
http://next.plnkr.co/edit/PrrKFvx3WbDFAXlk4ehH?p=preview